# Amazon Advertising API: ASINs report request returns “Missing campaign type”

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

**Request to API-Endpoint:**
POST https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v2/asins/report

**Official documentation:**
https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/sponsored-products/2/reports

**Headers:**

```
Authorization: Bearer Atza|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/json
Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Amazon-Advertising-API-SCOPE: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Request:**

```
 {
    "segment": "query",
    "reportDate":"20200201",
    "metrics": "campaignName,campaignId,adGroupName,adGroupId,keywordId,keywordText,asin,otherAsin,currency,matchType,attributedUnitsOrdered30d,attributedUnitsOrdered30dOtherSKU,attributedSales30dOtherSKU"
 }
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "code": "400",
    "details": "Missing campaign type",
    "requestId": "7Q8PMWM2618KAS0VEG87"
}
```

**Question:**

I think the error message is misleading (because i checked the documentation twice and because of my former experiences with the API).
But what is the real error? How can i get a ASINs report?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked Amazon Support and they replied:

> "Asin report would need campaignType in the payload to succeed the operation. We have a documentation update pending on this. Please be noted that query segmentation is only allowed for keyword, target and productAds report. An example payload:-

> GET [https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v2/asins/report"](https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v2/asins/report%22)

```
{
    "reportDate":"20200201",
    "campaignType": "sponsoredProducts",
    "metrics":"campaignName,
               campaignId,
               adGroupName,
               adGroupId,
               keywordId,
               keywordText,
               asin,
               otherAsin,
               currency,
               matchType,
               attributedUnitsOrdered30d,
               attributedUnitsOrdered30dOtherSKU,
               attributedSales30dOtherSKU"
}
```